# Definition of p-Laplace system

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian, weak-derivatives

I am thinking about the recently noticed p-Laplace system

$div\left(|Du|^{p-2}D u_i \right)= 0$ in $E\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $1\leq i \leq n $

where $u:E\subset \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$.
What is $Du$ exactly? It should be a matrix instead of a vector (gradient), right? If so, which norm is meant with $|Du|$? I would assume that this is the usual spectral norm used on matrix spaces but I am not certain. I understood the scalar case, i.e. $n=1$, but I have never before seen any system like this.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So $u=(u_1,\dots,u_n)$ is a function from $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, or what?

Comment: Hi, I edited my post. The dimension of $E$ does not have to coincide with the system dimension $n$.

Comment: When $n=1$ it's just the Euclidean length of the gradient vector, so my first guess would be that in general it's just the square root of the sum of the squares of all the matrix elements.